# has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently using the community version of JasperReports Server 8.0.0 and I am trying to run a report via rest_v2 using javascript, the problem is that I get the error that I put in the title, I am using everything from the localhost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://joeuser:joeuser@localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/MA032.xls?AMB=yyyy&INS=NV&NOM_PROD=nutri&FECHA_INI=2022-01-01&FECHA_FIN=2022-01-31", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using token based authentication and would like to pass a token via HTTP header. Here is sample code in JRS 7.8.0:

```
visualize({
    auth: {
        token: token,
        preAuth: true,
        tokenName: "pp",
    loginFn: function(properties, request) {
        return request({
            url: url,
            type: "get",
            headers: {
                pp: properties.token,
                Accept: "application/json"
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

}

The method will fail with an error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myCustomApp/jasperserver-pro/' from origin 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field pp is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Since jasperserver 7.8.0 all the CORS policy are pre-defined in the WEB-INF/applicationContext-security-pro-web.xml as given below :

```
<property name="allowedHeaders">
                                <list>
                                    <value>Cache-Control</value>
                                    <value>X-Suppress-Basic</value>
                                    <value>Origin</value>
                                    <value>Accept</value>
                                    <value>X-Requested-With</value>
                                    <value>Content-Type</value>
                                    <value>Pragma</value>
                                    <value>accept-timezone</value>
                                    <value>withCredentials</value>
                                    <value>X-Remote-Domain</value>
                                    <value>X-Is-Visualize</value>
                                    <value>x-jrs-base-url</value>
                                    <value>Content-Disposition</value>
                                    <value>Content-Description</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
```

To resolve the error you need to add your principalParameter name in above allowedHeaders list as PP. save the changes and restart the server.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code to startup:

```
app.UseCors(x => x
               .AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader());
```